# SI Server side error Could not convert reply: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for type

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson, converters

I have spent some time trying to figure out what might be causing the problem and no break throughs.  I have a rest service which works fine for xml response but complains for json content-type with the following error

> Could not convert reply: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for type [com.ngt.response.model.ResponseModel] and accept types [[application/json]
>   ]

---

I am using SI 2.2.6 and Spring 3.2.4.  I have all of the jackson dependencies in place.  The code and config snippets follow:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundRestGateway" supported-methods="POST"  
    request-channel="input.channel" reply-channel="output.channel" mapped-request-headers="X-*,HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
    mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS" path="/rest/{version}/{UUID}" reply-timeout="50000">
    <int-http:header name="UUID" expression="#pathVariables.UUID" />
    <int-http:header name="version" expression="#pathVariables.version" />

</int-http:inbound-gateway>

ResponseModel

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Diagnostics") @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @JsonRootName("Diagnostics") @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class ResponseModel implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("VehicleInfo")
    @XmlElement(name = "VehicleInfo")
    private VehicleInfoResponse vehicleInfoResponse=new VehicleInfoResponse();
```

---

I notice that the response is always converted to XML.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: The only way I could resolve it is through adding a transformer.  There must be a better way. I am sending the content-type in the header as application/json and yet it does not work.

Comment: Hi. I suppose there is no other way than using converter or embedded transformer. Why you want to omit transformer? I think, transformer declaration explicitly notifies that result will be converted to json. Please, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a more elegant solution, like the http converters being able to check the content-type and converting to json.